# How can I get Chrome to accept the OPTIONS response and send my Flutter app's POST request?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, http, cors

I am running into some problems while developing a Flutter app on Chrome that interacts with a RESTful server on an ESP32 microcontroller that uses Webserver.h; the POST request in questions has headers = **{'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'}**

The POST request in question works just fine on a native Windows app as well as Postman, which don't restrict POST requests. But Chrome does, sending instead an OPTIONS /blink request. Our server sends back a 204 response with these headers, attempting to please its Chrome overlord's CORS policy :

```
    void handleOptionsNoGet() {
    json.clear();
    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS");
    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,       Accept");
    server.send(204); // code 204: No Content
    json.clear();
    }
```

I checked with Wireshark that this 204 HTTP response was being sent and it indeed is, yet, Chrome still doesn't let my POST request through, so every time I attempt to send it is turned into an OPTIONS one and no POST request is ever sent, blocking my app from doing its job. Any help maybe? ChatGPT has not managed to fix this problem, despite multiple attempts.

Tried to run the request on Postman and on a non CORS restricted app, such as Windows. Both worked just fine. Tried it on Edge, it was also blocked. I assume it has to do with a CORS policy problem, but my server's response explicitly allows the headers that are in the request so I'm just confused.

Comment: Your client most likely includes a request header that is not allowed in your CORS configuration. Inspect the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header in the preflight request.

Comment: Try removing the random spaces, e.g. `POST, OPTIONS` -> `POST,OPTIONS`

Comment: These headers work with most Flutter web apps `accept,accept-encoding,authorization,content-type,dnt,origin,user-agent`

Comment: @RichardHeap FWIW, spaces in the values of CORS response headers are immaterial. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#header-value-get-decode-and-split